# 6.5 gm diesel dies shortly after you start to drive it idles for a good 40 minutes

Tags: chevrolet, diesel, stall, truck

A buddy of mine has a 1999 6.5 turbo diesel it seems to lose fuel pressure in the filter cap an then stalls he also has the wastegate held open I figure the lack of power is due to the wastegate being held open but not sure bout the fuel pressure maybe weak fuel pump

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! No clue why he'd want to hold open the waste gate as that pretty much kills power like nobodies business. It will also waste fuel, because there's not as much boost occurring as there is fuel going into the engine. I'm sure he rolls coal with the best of them, but whatever. Have you (or he) tested the fuel pressure? The hi-pressure fuel pump could very well be the problem, but check the supply side first. First thing I'd do is get the waste gate in working order and go from there.

Comment: Start simple: check the OBD codes and fuel pressure. Replacing the fuel filter may be all you need, don't assume anything, test be methodical, don't jump around from one theory to another, spending money as you go.

Comment: If the wastegate is being held open, doesn't that mean that the turbo is not spinning up at all? If there's any sort of boost gauge / indicator, I wouldn't expect to see anything above atmospheric pressure. If the ECU is still thinking that it should be sending as much fuel as full boost requires, I'd expect that the engine is getting far too much fuel. If this is the case then, at best, this vehicle is wasting a lot of money at the current price of diesel.